# Porting functional programming code to Linq

Tags: c#, beginner, haskell, functional-programming, linq

I am very new to C# programming, so for practice I thought I would try to port a simple haskell function over to Linq. From *learn you a haskell*, there is the following implementation of powerset:

```
powerset :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerset xs = filterM (\x -> [True, False]) xs
```

Where `filterM` is defined like so

```
filterM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM _ []     = return []
filterM p (x:xs) = do
  flg <- p x
  ys  <- filterM p xs
  return (if flg then x:ys else ys)
```

De-sugaring the do notation and specializing to `m = list`, this is

```
filterM :: (a -> [Bool]) -> [a] -> [[a]]
filterM _ []     = [[]]
filterM p (x:xs) = 
  p x >>= (\flg ->
    filterM p xs >>= (\ys ->
      if flg then [x:ys] else [ys]))
```

So, porting the above code to Linq, this is what I have:

```
//prepend taken from a stackexchange post
static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, T val)
    {
        yield return val;
        foreach (T t in seq)
        {
            yield return t;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static List<List<T>> FilterND<T>(Func<T, List<bool>> preds, List<T> xs)
    {
        if (xs.Any())
        {
            //unrolling haskell do notation.
            //>>= becomes SelectMany
            return
            preds(xs.First()).SelectMany(b =>
            FilterND(preds, xs.Skip(1).ToList()).SelectMany(ys =>
                b ?
                new List<List<T>> { ys.Prepend(xs.First()).ToList() } :
                new List<List<T>> { ys }
            ))
            .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<List<T>> { new List<T> { } }; //[[]]
        }
    }

    static List<List<T>> Powerset<T>(List<T> xs)
    {
        Func<T, List<bool>> preds = (x => new List<bool> { true, false });
        return FilterND<T>(preds, xs);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        var pow = Powerset(test);
        foreach (var xs in pow)
        {
            Console.Write("[");
            foreach (var x in xs)
            {
                Console.Write(x);
            }
            Console.Write("]\n");
        }
    }
}
```

My main questions are:

1. How do I go about making things lazy in the correct places?
2. In what ways should I be qualifying my input (ref, out, etc)?
3. Is it even possible to make this sort of code run fast?

Comment: The very first change you may want to implement is to drop `List<T>` in favor of `IEnumerable<T>`. Code will be both  greatly simplified and faster (and enumeration will be lazyly evaluated)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Comments are for seeking clarification to the question. Please put all suggestions for improvements in answers, even if the answer is brief.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've hardly written a line of Haskell in my life... but hopefully that isn't too important since you're happy with plain old concrete types here.

---

As Adriano Repetti said in his comment, working with `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>` - or pretty much anything else - allows for lazy evaluation: your `Prepend` extension method is a beautiful example of this already. Most implementations of `IEnumerable` are nice enough to not break when you try to use them in funky ways through LINQ, so don't worry about that. If you are worried about that, then just `.ToArray()` the input (or use an `IReadOnlyList<T>`) so that you know you can trust the input.

Doing a quick job of replacing all those lists with `IEnumerable<T>`s and removing the calls to `.ToList()` gives this:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> FilterND<T>(Func<T, IEnumerable<bool>> preds, IEnumerable<T> xs)
{
    if (xs.Any())
    {
        return
            preds(xs.First()).SelectMany(b =>
                FilterND(preds, xs.Skip(1)).SelectMany(ys =>
                    b
                        ? new [] { ys.Prepend(head) }
                        : new [] { ys }
                    )
                );
    }
    else
    {
        return new [] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    }
}
```

Note that I use arrays for 'throw away' fixed-length enumerables: they will be (marginally) faster, and provide a *much* tidier syntax. `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` is used rather than `new T[0]` or `new T[] { }` just because it is absolutely clear that I just want something empty.

`Prepend` is lazy, so is `SelectMany`: this whole package is now lazy. You can kind-of ratify this by putting a print line in `Prepend`, and writing the following code:

```cs
var ps = PowersetNess.PowerSet(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });

int si = 0;
foreach (var s in ps)
{
    Console.WriteLine(si++ + "\t" + string.Join(", ", s));
}
```

Without the print in `Prepend` the output will look like this:

```cs
0       1, 2, 3
1       1, 2
2       1, 3
3       1
4       2, 3
5       2
6       3
7
```

With the prepend, we can see that the calls are interspersed everywhere, which implies that something is being lazy.

```cs
Prepend!
Prepend!
Prepend!
0       1, 2, 3
Prepend!
Prepend!
1       1, 2
Prepend!
Prepend!
2       1, 3
Prepend!
3       1
Prepend!
Prepend!
4       2, 3
Prepend!
5       2
Prepend!
6       3
7
```

Naturally, if you insert those `.ToList()` calls back in, then you will find all the `Prepend!`s at the top, because you are forcing evaluation and caching.

Now indulge me while I pull out a couple of variables and rename `b` to `includeHead`...

```cs
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> FilterND<T>(Func<T, IEnumerable<bool>> preds, IEnumerable<T> xs)
{
    if (xs.Any())
    {
        T head = xs.First();
        IEnumerable<T> tail = xs.Skip(1);

        return
            preds(head).SelectMany(includeHead =>
                FilterND(preds, tail).SelectMany(ys =>
                    includeHead
                        ? new [] { ys.Prepend(head) }
                        : new [] { ys }
                    )
                );
    }
    else
    {
        // just the empty set
        return new [] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    }
}
```

Perhaps it is somehow clearer in Haskell to use `>>=` rather than a classic map, but the inner `SelectMany` can just be a `Select`, which will improve performance and reduce clutter rather.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> FilterND<T>(Func<T, IEnumerable<bool>> preds, IEnumerable<T> xs)
{
    if (xs.Any())
    {
        T head = xs.First();
        IEnumerable<T> tail = xs.Skip(1);

        return
            preds(head).SelectMany(includeHead =>
                FilterND(preds, tail).Select(ys =>
                    includeHead
                        ? Cons(head, ys)
                        : ys
                    )
                );
    }
    else
    {
        // just the empty set
        return new [] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    }
}
```

You can also externalise the `includeHead` check, which will of course reduce overhead, and (I think) makes the whole method *much* more understandable.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> FilterND<T>(Func<T, IEnumerable<bool>> preds, IEnumerable<T> xs)
{
    if (xs.Any())
    {
        T head = xs.First();
        IEnumerable<T> tail = xs.Skip(1);

        return
            preds(head).SelectMany(includeHead =>
                includeHead
                    ? FilterND(preds, tail).Select(ys => Cons(head, ys))
                    : FilterND(preds, tail)
                );
    }
    else
    {
        // just the empty set
        return new [] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    }
}
```

---

To answer your question 2: you don't need or want any `out`, `ref`, or `in` here. You *could* write a `Decons` method with `out` params to cleanly extract the head and tail of a list (shown below for fun), but it's probably not worth it, and doesn't have the same typing gaurentees as proper pattern matching.

```cs
public static bool Decons<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, out T head, out IEnumerable<T> tail)
{
    if (list.Any())
    {
        head = list.First();
        tail = list.Skip(1);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        head = default(T);
        tail = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I was using such a method in 'real' code it would be called `TryDeconstruct` or something. The pattern matching feature that are slowly being fed into C# may one day allow code looks like `if (vs is (head, tail))`, but I don't keep on top of that stuff.

Here is a (in my opinion *very* readable) version which uses a pair of nested `foreach` loops, and the `Decons` method.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> FilterND<T>(Func<T, IEnumerable<bool>> preds, IEnumerable<T> xs)
{
    if (xs.Decons(out var head, out var tail))
    {
        foreach (var includeHead in preds(head))
        {
            foreach (var partialSubSet in FilterND(preds, tail))
            {
                if (includeHead)
                    yield return partialSubSet.Prepend(head);
                else
                    yield return partialSubSet;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // just the empty set
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

I hope that flood of C# was of some interest!

---

One final thing: you can tidy the definition of `preds` a bit (should it be `predicates`?) by using a local function.

```cs
Func<T, List<bool>> preds = (x => new List<bool> { true, false });
bool[] predicates(T x) => new bool[] { true, false };
```

This is just a matter of taste really (slightly surprised you didn't go with `return FilterND<T>(x => new bool[] { true, false }, xs);`). You could reduce the number of allocations by creating a single `bool[]` and always returning it, if performance is a serious concern, but this is the wrong place to be looking for a performance advantage.

*P.S.: thanks for posting this, I had a lot of fun with it*

Comment: You're the first person I see here that puts closing `)` _properly_ in the next line! Nicely formatted code ;-D

Comment: @t3chb0t honestly I'm never quite sure how to indent them! I'll have to try to be consistent from now on ;)

Comment: Very nice and well written answer!

Answer (score 4):

Just a minor note to add to the existing answer: `Prepend` can be constructed quite cleanly from standard Linq methods as

```
static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, T val) =>
    Enumerable.Repeat(val, 1).Concat(seq);
```

or (arguably less readable here, but more consistent with the style in the other answer)

```
static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, T val) =>
    new [] { val }.Concat(seq);
```